# Page slows down because a lot "scroll" and "resize" events are binding to window

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize, scroll, window

I'm a begginer in jquery and javascript. I have a big trouble with my function, which gets two parameters - image source and array of img sources.

```
function loadPicture(pic_src, _getarray)
{
    var picture_index = _getarray.indexOf(pic_src);
    var array_last = _getarray.length - 1;

    var big_source = pic_src;                       
    var big_source = 'pictures/' + big_source.substring(big_source.search("thumbs/th_")+10);

    var wwidth = $(window).width();
    var wheight = $(window).height();

    $("body").css({ 'overflow' : 'hidden' });

    $("#pic_loader img.single_picture").remove();
    $("#pic_loader").css({ 
                    'width' : wwidth,
                    'height' : wheight      
                    });

    $("#pic_loader").fadeIn();
    $("#pic_loader").append('<img data-original="'+big_source+'" alt="" class="single_picture" />');

    $("img.single_picture").css({ 
        'max-height' : wheight - 120 + 'px',
        'max-width' : wwidth - 120 + 'px',
        'margin-top' : parseInt(wheight/16) + 'px'
    });

    $("img.single_picture").lazyload({
        effect : "fadeIn",
        skip_invisible : false,
        load : function() 
            {
                $("#pic_loader").css({ 'background' : '#000' });
            }
    });

    $("#next_pic").click( function()
    {
        if(picture_index == array_last)
        {
            loadPicture(_getarray[0],_getarray);
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            loadPicture(_getarray[picture_index+1],_getarray);
            return false;
        }
    } );

    $("#prev_pic").click( function()
    {
        if(picture_index == 0)
        {
            loadPicture(_getarray[array_last],_getarray);
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            loadPicture(_getarray[picture_index-1],_getarray);
            return false;
        }
    } );
}
```

Problem occurs when user clicks prev_pic or next_pic link, it correctly loads picture into viewer (`#pic_loader`) but it doubles `scroll` and `resize` events every time when recursion happens, then browser dramatically slowing down. I don't know how to handle this.

["events screenshot"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xci3z.png)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where 'scroll' and 'resize' are coming from, but you could try adding a clear at the beginning of loadPicture:

```
function loadPicture(pic_src, _getarray)
{
    resize = [];
    scroll = [];
```

Comment: Doesn't work this way. Resize and scroll are event handlers which firing when $(window) are scrolled or resized (I don't really know if I'm right).